# ImageMagick morphology - missing kernels - UnrecognizedKernelType

Tags: imagemagick, image-morphology

I am trying to use any of those:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#erode

but it only returns an error message:

```
convert original.png -morphology Erode Octagon converted.png
 convert: UnrecognizedKernelType `Octagon' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1967
```

The same error occurs with `-morphology Dilate Octagon`.

Comment: What's returned by running `identify -list morphology` command?

Comment: Correlate
Convolve
Dilate
Erode
Close
Open
DilateIntensity
ErodeIntensity
CloseIntensity
OpenIntensity
DilateI
ErodeI
CloseI
OpenI
EdgeOut
EdgeIn
Edge
TopHat
BottomHat
Distance --- but I can't pass only Erode, because it says that `convert: option requires an argument` and when passing numbers, nothing happens... I mean output is the same as input.

Comment: Seems like my version is old one, but I can't install new one since  it is Debian 4. So it means I can't use that at all? Octagon was added in later versions...

Comment: Yep. With your old version, your limited to the values returned by `identify -list kernel`

Comment: Not really... I found solution... the valid arguments are: Diamond, Square, Disk, Plus, Cross, Rectangle, Ring...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to that question for future generations:

`Octagon` shape was added in `6.6.9.x` version of `ImageMagick` but with older versions you can use:

```
Diamond,
Square,
Disk,
Plus,
Cross,
Rectangle,
Ring
```

And those work fine.

You can even define their size, like this:

> convert original.png -morphology Erode Square:2:2 converted.png

Just play around yourself.

Comment: FlashThunder, you should *upvote* plus *accept* your own answer. There is nothing wrong with doing so!

Comment: Ok thank you, I will do that accept it, but I need to wait 2 days (8 hours from now).